High fidelity implies low entropy
I was reading the security proof of QKD by   Lo-Chau. One of their main idea is to bound the entropy of the eavesdropper if the singlet states are of high fidelity. Here I summarized the first lemma:
Let singlet state be $|\psi\rangle =  (|01\rangle - |10\rangle)\sqrt{2}$, then if the fidelity of $\langle \psi|^{\otimes n} \rho | \psi \rangle^{\otimes n} > 1 - \delta$, with $\delta <<1$, then the von Neumann entropy $S(\rho) < - (1-\delta) \log_2(1-\delta)- \delta \log_2 \frac{\delta}{2^{2n}-1}$.
In the proof, it is mentioned that if the the fidelity is bounded, then the largest eigenvalue of the density matrix $\rho$ must be larger than $1-\delta$. Then the entropy of $\rho$ is bounded by a diagonal density matrix of $\rho_0$, with diagonal entries of $\{1-\delta, \frac{\delta}{2^{2n}-1} , \dots, \frac{\delta}{2^{2n}-1}\}$
My question: Why does the bounded fidelity implies the largest eigenvalue must be larger than $1-\delta$? I think what the author means is that this eigenvalue correspond to eigenstate of $| \psi \rangle \langle \psi|$, and the remaining eigenstates has uniform eigenvalues of $\frac{\delta}{2^{2n}-1}$. But if this eigenvalue does not correspond to a singlet eigenstate, is it possible to make a density matrix with eigenvalues less than $1-\delta$, but still give fidelity higher than $1-\delta$?

This is easiest to see if you diagonalise the state
\begin{align}
    \rho = \sum_j p_j |\phi_j \rangle\langle \phi_j|,
\end{align}
where the $|\phi_j\rangle$ are orthogonal and normalized, and the $p_j$ are non-negative and sum to $1$. Taking the fidelity with any pure state (say $|\psi\rangle$) we obtain
\begin{align}
    \langle{\psi}|\rho|\psi\rangle &= \sum_j p_j \langle\psi |\phi_j\rangle\langle \phi_j|\psi\rangle \\
    &= \sum_j p_j \lvert\langle \phi_j|\psi\rangle \rvert^2,
\end{align}
the fidelity is a convex combination of the eigenvalues, $p_j$, of $\rho$ with weights given by the numbers $\lvert\langle \phi_j|\psi\rangle \rvert^2$ (which are non-negative and sum to $1$ so this is a true convex combination), it therefore can't be larger than the larger than the largest eigenvalue.
For a slightly more formal argument let $p_\text{max} = 1-\delta$ be the largest eigenvalue of $\rho$ then clearly
\begin{align}
    \langle{\psi}|\rho|\psi\rangle 
    = \sum_j p_j \lvert\langle \phi_j|\psi\rangle \rvert^2 &\leq \sum_j p_\text{max} \lvert\langle \phi_j|\psi\rangle \rvert^2 = p_\text{max} \sum_j  \lvert\langle \phi_j|\psi\rangle \rvert^2 = p_\text{max}.
\end{align}

But isn't it possible to create a density matrix, say consisting of eigenstates with inner product with singlet states close to 1, such that the largest eigenvalue might not be larger than $1-\delta$ for each  eigenstates, but their sums gives a fidelity larger than $1-\delta$?

@JasonWS In my answer I proved it is not - an intuitive reason for why this doesn't work is that the density matrix is self-adjoint (or Hermitian if you prefer) so its eigenstates are orthogonal (and may be assumed to be normalized), if the inner product of one of the eigenstates with the singlet is very big the inner product of the others with the singlet has to be small because they are orthogonal. In the proof this appears as the statement that the $|\langle\phi_j|\psi\rangle|^2$ sum to $1$ (and not something larger than $1$.

What I got confused is that the largest eigenvalue $p_{max}$ could correspond to any eigenstate, which means it could correspond to an eigenstate with low inner product with the singlet state, say an orthogonal state with singlet state. In that case, isn't the fidelity gonna be less than $1-\delta$?

@JasonWS Yes, it is possible to have states for which the fidelity with the singlet is very low (for example its very easy to find examples of states for which the fidelity with the singlet is $0$). Thats fine though, the proof is saying IF the fidelity is high, THEN the entropy is low. It doesn't matter if the fidelity is sometimes low (although in those cases you won't be able to get a good bound on the entropy).

I see, I think I got confused by the if statement, thank you very much for the explanations!
